# Replace double backslash in linux php application

Tags: php, linux, composer-php

I have a rather naive question. In wamp environment I used composer in order to input some library and I use it like this:

```
use Hpar\PrestashopBridge\PrestashopBridge;
```

However in linux environment I get the following error:

> mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>   Hpar\PrestashopBridge\PrestashopBridge::redirect() in
>   /var/www/vhosts/example.com/

(it replaces the backslash with double backslash). How can I solve it?

Comment: The message says it all, you are calling an undefined method of `PrestashopBridge`, method "redirect" is not defined. Why do you think it is because of replaced characters?

Comment: Because it is working in local server and in logs I can see that in second line it replaces with double backslash

Comment: Could you open the mentioned file on the server and check if the redirect method is defined?